# Finding a stud (i.e., in a stud wall:)

Tags: optimization

During a thread in a private usenet newsgroup, involving finding a stud in a stud wall, somebody posted what I believe is the typical procedure (when the typical hardware store studfinder doesn't work)...

> Scott D wrote:
>    ...take a a very thin long nail and hammer it in to a random place.
>    Now try it again two inches to the right and then keep going,
>    making a line of holes until you find a stud.
>    --scott

But that got me thinking about whether or not that typical test-hole-distribution procedure is optimal, whereby I followed up...

off-topic (and just curious): so is that mathematically optimal?,
i.e., after, say, $10,000$ trials, what test-hole procedure gives you
the minimal average #holes drilled/nailed before finding a stud?
      Suppose studs are $t$ inches thick (default $2.0$"), and there's a distance $d$ (default $16.0$") between stud centers. Further,
suppose you want a hole within $c$ inches of a stud center, i.e.,
maybe you don't want just an edge, but default $c=t/2$ allows edges.
       Then let $h$ inches (default $h=t$) be your distance between test holes. Using the default values, then $h=2$" guarantees you'll get the
first stud to the right (or left) of your first test hole.
But maybe $h=3$" results, on average over many trials, in fewer
necessary holes. (Moreover, if $c<1$", then $h=2$", or other even
divisors of $d$, could go on forever.) Or maybe $h=2",3",2",3"...$,
or some other irregular pattern of holes is optimal.
      It's not even clear to me how to approach the problem for
a closed-form solution.

So is there any kind of closed-form solution for this kind of problem? Or at least a way to set it up such that it could be solved?

**E d i t
-----------------**
Several followups in that newsgroup suggested related (more general)
problems...

> - Kal wrote: This is called the Multi-Armed Bandit problem. When RAND was working
>     on it during WWII some smart-aleck suggested typing up the problem
>     in German and dropping leaflets to distract their war efforts.
> - dhs wrote: Morse, Phillip M, & Kimball, George E, How to Hunt a Submarine

In any case, the exact problem specified above is simple enough to program.
Below are some results for the given default values, $d=16,t=2,c=1$. Then the hole distribution is uniform, with $41$ sets of $50,000$ trials $1\le h\le3$ in increments $\Delta h=.05$. Displayed results are
**min<avg<max #holes** needed to find a stud, and then the average distance from stud center for that final hole.

Note that the naively-expected $h=2$ indeed seems to be the optimal choice. And I'd kind of expected the collection of numbers to be some more-or-less smooth function of $h$. But this expectation is not quite the case...

```
  For 50000 trials: h=1.000, 1 < avg#holes=7.525 < 15, avg_c=0.501
  For 50000 trials: h=1.050, 1 < avg#holes=7.290 < 15, avg_c=0.473
  For 50000 trials: h=1.100, 1 < avg#holes=7.008 < 14, avg_c=0.458
  For 50000 trials: h=1.150, 1 < avg#holes=6.787 < 14, avg_c=0.444
  For 50000 trials: h=1.200, 1 < avg#holes=6.564 < 13, avg_c=0.430
  For 50000 trials: h=1.250, 1 < avg#holes=6.345 < 13, avg_c=0.430
  For 50000 trials: h=1.300, 1 < avg#holes=6.155 < 12, avg_c=0.424
  For 50000 trials: h=1.350, 1 < avg#holes=5.980 < 12, avg_c=0.419
  For 50000 trials: h=1.400, 1 < avg#holes=5.817 < 11, avg_c=0.426
  For 50000 trials: h=1.450, 1 < avg#holes=5.671 < 11, avg_c=0.415
  For 50000 trials: h=1.500, 1 < avg#holes=5.526 < 11, avg_c=0.421
  For 50000 trials: h=1.550, 1 < avg#holes=5.403 < 11, avg_c=0.431
  For 50000 trials: h=1.600, 1 < avg#holes=5.276 < 10, avg_c=0.426
  For 50000 trials: h=1.650, 1 < avg#holes=5.183 < 10, avg_c=0.431
  For 50000 trials: h=1.700, 1 < avg#holes=5.060 < 10, avg_c=0.444
  For 50000 trials: h=1.750, 1 < avg#holes=4.950 < 9, avg_c=0.454
  For 50000 trials: h=1.800, 1 < avg#holes=4.844 < 9, avg_c=0.451
  For 50000 trials: h=1.850, 1 < avg#holes=4.754 < 9, avg_c=0.464
  For 50000 trials: h=1.900, 1 < avg#holes=4.678 < 9, avg_c=0.483
  For 50000 trials: h=1.950, 1 < avg#holes=4.590 < 9, avg_c=0.495
  For 50000 trials: h=2.000, 1 < avg#holes=4.505 < 8, avg_c=0.502
  For 50000 trials: h=2.050, 1 < avg#holes=4.592 < 15, avg_c=0.494
  For 50000 trials: h=2.100, 1 < avg#holes=4.672 < 15, avg_c=0.484
  For 50000 trials: h=2.150, 1 < avg#holes=4.766 < 15, avg_c=0.475
  For 50000 trials: h=2.200, 1 < avg#holes=4.852 < 15, avg_c=0.508
  For 50000 trials: h=2.250, 1 < avg#holes=4.962 < 15, avg_c=0.548
  For 50000 trials: h=2.300, 1 < avg#holes=5.642 < 27, avg_c=0.555
  For 50000 trials: h=2.350, 1 < avg#holes=4.830 < 13, avg_c=0.526
  For 50000 trials: h=2.400, 1 < avg#holes=4.864 < 13, avg_c=0.478
  For 50000 trials: h=2.450, 1 < avg#holes=4.971 < 13, avg_c=0.429
  For 50000 trials: h=2.500, 1 < avg#holes=5.043 < 13, avg_c=0.454
  For 50000 trials: h=2.550, 1 < avg#holes=5.085 < 13, avg_c=0.520
  For 50000 trials: h=2.600, 1 < avg#holes=5.585 < 19, avg_c=0.565
  For 50000 trials: h=2.650, 1 < avg#holes=9.195 < 49, avg_c=0.610
  For 50000 trials: h=2.700, 1 < avg#holes=6.763 < 29, avg_c=0.598
  For 50000 trials: h=2.750, 1 < avg#holes=5.381 < 17, avg_c=0.551
  For 50000 trials: h=2.800, 1 < avg#holes=4.880 < 11, avg_c=0.524
  For 50000 trials: h=2.850, 1 < avg#holes=4.926 < 11, avg_c=0.449
  For 50000 trials: h=2.900, 1 < avg#holes=4.968 < 11, avg_c=0.415
  For 50000 trials: h=2.950, 1 < avg#holes=5.022 < 11, avg_c=0.433
  For 50000 trials: h=3.000, 1 < avg#holes=5.058 < 11, avg_c=0.500
```

So that especially noticeable peak around $h=2.65$ is expanded below,
$2.6\le h\le2.7, \Delta h=0.005$...

```
  For 50000 trials: h=2.600, 1 < avg#holes=5.607 < 19, avg_c=0.568
  For 50000 trials: h=2.605, 1 < avg#holes=5.656 < 19, avg_c=0.569
  For 50000 trials: h=2.610, 1 < avg#holes=5.726 < 19, avg_c=0.579
  For 50000 trials: h=2.615, 1 < avg#holes=5.894 < 19, avg_c=0.587
  For 50000 trials: h=2.620, 1 < avg#holes=6.096 < 25, avg_c=0.588
  For 50000 trials: h=2.625, 1 < avg#holes=6.347 < 25, avg_c=0.592
  For 50000 trials: h=2.630, 1 < avg#holes=6.527 < 25, avg_c=0.597
  For 50000 trials: h=2.635, 1 < avg#holes=6.927 < 31, avg_c=0.600
  For 50000 trials: h=2.640, 1 < avg#holes=7.388 < 31, avg_c=0.604
  For 50000 trials: h=2.645, 1 < avg#holes=8.112 < 37, avg_c=0.608
  For 50000 trials: h=2.650, 1 < avg#holes=9.185 < 49, avg_c=0.609
  For 50000 trials: h=2.655, 1 < avg#holes=11.471 < 67, avg_c=0.618
  For 50000 trials: h=2.660, 1 < avg#holes=16.759 < 109, avg_c=0.620
  For 50000 trials: h=2.665, 1 < avg#holes=55.469 < 409, avg_c=0.627
  For 50000 trials: h=2.670, 1 < avg#holes=29.142 < 209, avg_c=0.622
  For 50000 trials: h=2.675, 1 < avg#holes=14.233 < 89, avg_c=0.619
  For 50000 trials: h=2.680, 1 < avg#holes=10.595 < 59, avg_c=0.615
  For 50000 trials: h=2.685, 1 < avg#holes=8.775 < 47, avg_c=0.609
  For 50000 trials: h=2.690, 1 < avg#holes=7.831 < 35, avg_c=0.607
  For 50000 trials: h=2.695, 1 < avg#holes=7.168 < 35, avg_c=0.602
  For 50000 trials: h=2.700, 1 < avg#holes=6.797 < 29, avg_c=0.599
```

And now that $h=2.665$ peak really stands out. It's not quite clear to me which number(s) are or aren't even divisors (or incommensurate in some other way) of which others to make that happen in this case. But the
somewhat goofy behavior suggests to me that there's not likely to be any
closed-form solution (or at least not any easily-discoverable one).

Comment: My vote is for buying a better studfinder :)

Comment: I can't help but think that a randomized trial attempt will work faster at high probability, but I haven't computed it.

Comment: @calcstudent I was thinking of a binary-search-like procedure, pick a random first hole, then $\pm d/2$ from that, and then keep halving the intervals. But since the initial conditions (stud centers and first hole) are random, I'd guess a "linear search" is just as good on average. A completely randomized search might have the potential disadvantage that it's "open-ended", so to speak. There'll be some trials that require lots of holes. Of course, that $h=2.665$ required lots more than I'd have guessed. On the other hand, $h<t$ is guaranteed to find a stud with $\le (d-t)/h$ holes.